# A/C outside pipe leaking water

Tags: hvac

I have 2 a/c units. One for upstairs and other for downstairs. I have 4 outside pipes for both a/c s. 2 pipes, one upper and one lower are on each side of house. My upstairs a/c unit isn’t cooling and noted water dripping out of one of the lower pipes outside. No visible water leakage noted inside of home. What could this mean? 
Thanks!

Comment: Probably means the primary drain is plugged, it’s overflowing into a drain pan which is the drainage you’re seeing outside, and there’s a float switch on the pan to prevent the air conditioner from running, so the pan won’t overflow and cause damage.

Comment: @tyson  looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Air conditioning by nature produces water.  As air is cooled it can’t hold as much water, the result is condensation.  It’s the same thing that happens on the outside of a glass of icy cold beverage on a hot day.  Air conditioners make a lot of condensation,  depending on the size of the unit and humidity in your area it could be a gallon an hour.

Normally this water leaves the air conditioner through a drain hose, that drain into your houses normal drain/sewer pipes. When the drain hose gets plugged the air conditioner will literally overflow.  If is an attic mounted unit the whole air conditioner will be installed in a secondary drain pan so that when the unit itself overflows the pan will catch the water to prevent it from damaging the ceiling in the room below the air conditioner.   The secondary drain usually goes outside so that the homeowner will realize something is wrong.

However, should that secondary drain run slowly, because it to is plugged up, then the drain pan will fill with water and overflow (damaging the ceiling in the room below).  So as final protection they add a float switch to the drain pan so that when it fills with water it will shut down the cooling (stopping the unit from pulling water out of the air) to prevent water damage.

What plugs up these drains? Dirt, gunk, algae, attic insulation all combine over time and create a plug that keeps the water from flowing.

The shorter story is your air conditioner needs maintenance and cleaning.